# OKHttpClient - Socket Read timed out issue

Tags: okhttp

I am getting lot of Socket Read Timout when I try to read a response from my 
post request. I am using OKHttpClient verion 3.11.0 with the following configuration:

```
@Bean
OkHttpClient okHttpClient() {
def loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor()
loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
Dispatcher dispatcher = new Dispatcher()
dispatcher.setMaxRequests(200)
dispatcher.setMaxRequestsPerHost(200)

return new OkHttpClient()
        .newBuilder()
        .eventListenerFactory(PrintingEventListener.FACTORY)
        .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
        .connectTimeout(30000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .readTimeout(30000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .dispatcher(dispatcher)
        .connectionPool(new ConnectionPool(200, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
        .addNetworkInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
        .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor).build()

}
```

The code to process the request and response is given below:

```
Response r = client.newCall(request).execute()
r.withCloseable { response ->
def returnable

if (response.header('Content-Type')?.contains('application/json')) {
    def body = response.body().string()
    if (body.trim().isEmpty()) {
        returnable = [:]
    } else {
        try {
            def result = new JsonSlurper().parseText(body)
            return result
        } catch (any) {
            log.error('Failed to parse json response: ' + body, any.message)
            throw any
        }
    }
} else if (response.header('Content-Type')?.contains('image/jpeg')) {
    returnable = response.body().bytes()
} else {
    returnable = response.body().string()
}
return returnable
```

}

I add event listener, I see that the httpclient call responseBodyStart event and it hangs there and when timeout seconds reached, the call failed and throw Socket Read timeout exception. Is there anything missing in my configuration?

> Event listener shows 
>       responseHeaderStart or responseBodyStart followed by connectionReleased after specified timeout(30s) reached?

Please find the event trace and exception trace below:

```
INFO  11097 : 2.1701E-5 -- callStart
INFO  11097 : 1.44572E-4 -- connectionAcquired
INFO  11097 : 0.001036047 -- requestHeadersStart
INFO  11097 : 0.001064492 -- requestHeadersEnd 
INFO  11097 : 0.001084433 -- requestBodyStart 
INFO  11097 : 0.001103787 -- requestBodyEnd
INFO  11097 : 0.001279736 -- responseHeadersStart
INFO  11097 : 1.007175496 -- responseHeadersEnd
INFO  11097 : 1.007247928 -- responseBodyStart
INFO  11097 : 31.082725087 -- connectionReleased
INFO  11097 : 31.083717147 -- callFailed
INFO  11097 : 31.092341876 --    
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:983)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:940)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
    at okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:140)
    at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:237)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.request(RealBufferedSource.java:68)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.require(RealBufferedSource.java:61)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.readHexadecimalUnsignedLong(RealBufferedSource.java:304)
    at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec$ChunkedSource.readChunkSize(Http1Codec.java:469)
    at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec$ChunkedSource.read(Http1Codec.java:449)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.request(RealBufferedSource.java:68)
    at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:241)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:213)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
    at okhttp3.Call$execute.call(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read [ask] and update your question with the relevant information. At the moment the question is difficult to answer based on the information you have provided.